# Distributed Cache is stuck in Starting

Tags: sharepoint, distributed-caching

I can't start or stop Distributed Cache in one of SharePoint 2013 WFE servers. It says "Starting" for the status in Central Admin. I'm getting server errors and I think Distributed Cache may be corrupting the data because of this. It got stuck in "Starting" status when I first ran below command.

Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance

When I try to stop it using below, I get "cacheHostInfo is null" error.

Stop-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance -Graceful

I get the same "cacheHostInfo is null" error when I run below script to delete the instance.

$instanceName ="SPDistributedCacheService Name=AppFabricCachingService"
$serviceInstance = Get-SPServiceInstance | ? {($*.service.tostring()) -eq $instanceName -and ($*.server.name) -eq $env:computername}
$serviceInstance.Unprovision()
$serviceInstance.Delete()

Any ideas how to resolve this?